# Error compiling with <list> C++

Tags: c++

I don't know why it doesn't compile of I erase the comment in line

```
/*******************************/
waitThread.push_front(workerID);
/******************************/
```

Only if I leave the comment, it compiles...otherwise, I get a long exception ending with "declared here"...

```
/usr/include/c++/4.6/thread:126:5: error: declared here
```

maybe there is some problem with the definition of ...
Can you explain me?

```
/*  g++ -std=c++0x -o manyThreads manyThreads.cpp -pthread */


#include <thread>
#include <iostream>
#include <mutex>
#include <time.h>
#include <list>


std::list<std::thread::id> myList;
std::mutex mutex;
std::list<std::thread> waitThread;

void insertList(std::thread::id identifier) {

mutex.lock();
myList.push_front(identifier);
mutex.unlock();

}

int main() {



std::list<std::thread::id>::iterator id;

std::list<std::thread>::iterator threadsIter;

int counter;


for(counter=0; counter<6; counter++) {

    std::thread workerID(insertList, workerID.get_id());

            /*******************************/
    waitThread.push_front(workerID);
            /******************************/
}


for(threadsIter=waitThread.begin(); threadsIter !=waitThread.end();threadsIter++)    {
    threadsIter->join();
}


for(id=myList.begin(); id != myList.end(); id++) {
    std::cout << *id << "\n";
}

return 0;
}
```

Comment: Why do you only let us see the *last* line of the compiler error? Does the rest contain state secrets? Do we need to sign an NDA to see it?

Comment: I guess 99% of gcc errors end with that line :)

Comment: it's interest because usually the first error (and first line) contains the most important piece of information... :p  maybe it **is** state secret!

Comment: Sorry, I guess I am bad influenced by too much python programming where instead a thread is coyping into a list...

Comment: In most languages you'd be right because variables contain references to objects, not the objects themselves, so copying the variable just makes a new reference to the same thread (in this case) C++ doesn't work like that though

Comment: But if I can't create a list lf threads and the main process creates an arbitrary number of threads, how can I join() them all?

Answer (score 4):

std::thread is not copyable so you can't call push_front with it. It makes no sense to copy a thread, what would it do?

You can perhaps move the thread onto the list using

```
waitThread.push_front(std::move(workerID));
```

which will of course invalidate the thread object after that line.

However this line looks strange too :-

```
std::thread workerID(insertList, workerID.get_id());
```

I doubt it's valid to call get_id on an object that isn't constructed at that point.

Answer (score 2):

`std::thread` is not copyable so you would have to move it in:

```
waitThread.push_front(std::move(workerID));
```

alternatively, you can move it by passing a temporary:

```
waitThread.push_front(std::thread(insertList, workerID.get_id());
```

Answer (score 1):

It's not a comment, but a valid and (probably) essential statement in your program:

```
/*******************************/ -- comment
waitThread.push_front(workerID); -- statement
/******************************/ --comment
```

Comment: +1 haha this is a good interpretation of an otherwise cryptic question.  he incorrectly thinks the middle line is also a comment.

Comment: Exactly. That's why it works (at least according to the author) when nothing is deleted.